# Implementation of knowledge flow environment in Weka using training and test data set

Tags: classification, random-forest, weka, naivebayes, roc

I like to compare the various ROC curves, which are build by various classifier using **WEKA KNOWLEDGE FLOW** platform. I have a training data set and a test data set. I want to build the model using training dataset and then want to supply test dataset to build the ROC curves. As per my understanding I have created a knowledge flow environment.

[image: Picture 1]

However, I am not sure about my implementation.

Comment: Why do you have a `CrossValidationFoldMaker` in there if you have dedicated train and test sets?

Comment: When I trained the model using training set on Weka workbench I used 5fold cross validation.

Comment: You use cross-validation when you only have a single dataset. Since you have a dedicated test, you need to use it accordingly. Remove the CrossValidationFoldMaker, especially since your question talks about using the test set for building the ROC curves (and not muddle it with any statistics that you derive from CV).

Comment: So, you are saying if I have a dedicated test set I don't need cross validation for the dedicated training set. right?

Comment: Yes, you do either or.